# What means SecTaskLoadEntlitlements failed error=22

Tags: performance

I'm trying to run a game I bought from Steam: Dread Out. It starts the main screen, options, etc. but when I'll play the first level, it does not load the level. The loading screen stays forever, with music and tips. The app seams to be running but no content is loading and no error is dispatched. I did put a flag in the console and got the messages while running the app:

```
06/05/16 22:44:01,529 launchservicesd[83]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
06/05/16 22:44:01,534 launchservicesd[83]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
06/05/16 22:44:01,646 appleeventsd[56]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
06/05/16 22:44:01,709 dreadout[31113]: WARNING: The Gestalt selector gestaltSystemVersion is returning 10.9.4 instead of 10.11.4. This is not a bug in Gestalt -- it is a documented limitation. Use NSProcessInfo's operatingSystemVersion property to get correct system version number.
Call location:
06/05/16 22:44:01,710 dreadout[31113]: 0   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8f1466df ___Gestalt_SystemVersion_block_invoke + 113
06/05/16 22:44:01,710 dreadout[31113]: 1   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff969bc40b _dispatch_client_callout + 8
06/05/16 22:44:01,710 dreadout[31113]: 2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff969bc303 dispatch_once_f + 67
06/05/16 22:44:01,710 dreadout[31113]: 3   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8f0d2fbc _Gestalt_SystemVersion + 987
06/05/16 22:44:01,710 dreadout[31113]: 4   CarbonCore                          0x00007fff8f0d27d0 Gestalt + 139
06/05/16 22:44:01,710 dreadout[31113]: 5   dreadout                            0x000000010071d70c _ZN12GraphicsCaps6InitGLEv + 5468
06/05/16 22:44:01,710 dreadout[31113]: 6   dreadout                            0x00000001007137d0 _Z17CreateGLGfxDevicev + 64
06/05/16 22:44:01,718 coreaudiod[167]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
06/05/16 22:44:02,957 WindowServer[10829]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "dreadout" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
06/05/16 22:44:08,511 WindowServer[10829]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "dreadout" after 6.55 seconds [0.15fps] (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds [1.00fps])
06/05/16 22:44:08,514 launchservicesd[83]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
06/05/16 22:44:08,514 launchservicesd[83]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
06/05/16 22:44:09,048 launchservicesd[83]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22
06/05/16 22:44:45,793 WindowServer[10829]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x042731c0 device: 0x7fbb615119b0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
```

There is this "SecTaskLoadEntitlements" all over, might be the source of failure. Do you know what it means?

Edit: Mac OS X 10.11.4

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need a bit of introduction to understand what SecTaskLoadEntitlements really is/does:

An application (.app) in OS X is really a folder containing a number of files, including the actual program, resources (graphics, sounds, etc) as well as system files such as plist files.

One of these plist files contains a descriptions of the application's entitlements. An entitlement is either that the application "can do" a certain thing, or that it has permission to do a certain thing.

Examples on OS X would be for an app to have the permission to get read-only access to your Music folder, or that it is allowed to interact with Bluetooth devices, record from your microphone, etc.

Application on the OS X App Store are required to use entitlements in so that that they're required to be sandboxed, which is an entitlement in itself.

In order to make sure that entitlements cannot be changed or unrightfully gained, the entitlements are "signed". This means that the developer of the application uses a specific cryptographic key to "sign" the entitlements.

OS X checks the signature when loading in new applications, and only if it is signed correctly will it load the entitlements and apply them to the program.

Your error message means that the "launchd" program tried to load in the entitlements for an application, but it failed with error number 22. The number 22 means that an invalid argument (parameter) was given.

This completes the explanation of what SecTaskLoadEntitlements is.

To answer your main question you need to know what launchd is. Launchd in general is the first program started when you boot OS X - it has process identifier number 1. Its job is to start all the other programs necessary for booting your computer. It can also start programs based on time and events, such as for example hardware changes.

Therefore the log messages you see are not necessarily linked to the problem you're having. Launchd is running continually no matter if you're playing the game or not. There is no indication that the log messages relate to your game as per the information you have given. It is thus unlikely that the problem with your game has anything to do with SecTaskLoadEntitlements.

I would write a message to the Dread Out support to ask for a fix.

Comment: I tried to contact the developers but got no answer. There is a lot of reports in Steam community of this same failure of this game in Mac OS X, and I suspect it's related to permissions, and would be a problem that users can fix. They probably build this version before El Capitan, so might be related with some security improvement...

Comment: You could try running the game from the command line to see if it outputs any debug information. If you can't find anything there, try using dtrace to get extra information. You will probably need to disable System Integrity Protection. However, I wouldn't spend any more time on the SecTaskLoadEntitlement log message - it is very unlikely that it is the cause of your problems.

Comment: I created an account to upvote this great answer.

Comment: MORE INFO: If there was a problem with game "dreadout"s info.plist, would likely see "SecTaskLoadEntitlements" line, but starting with "dreadout" instead of "launchservicesd". Would need to look carefully to see WHEN those lines happen. If they really do happen at the time the game (app) is launched, then perhaps there is some connection with the problem. (A separate process that the app launches? Speculation.) I see such a line starting with "coreaudiod": perhaps app is waiting on something related to audio that is improperly configured.